What to do if OP forever offline?
There are various questions on quant.SE which were asked by some user who then never goes online again.
It is probably not surprising that no answer will hence be ever accepted. I understand that this is a usual risk, however as I was told in this post, an unanswered question hurts the rating of the quant.SE site to graduate from its beta status.
So is there a way to accept an answer e.g. by moderator or to close the question for "not being online"?

Then it's up to the community to give up votes to the best answer, see this post by Jeff Atwood.
I don't really like this either but that's the way it is and I guess an alternative would have it's own set of drawbacks.
The people at Stack Exchange are reevaluating the criteria for graduation and I think they will handle this case well and that these unaccepted answers do not hinder our graduation. A bit more questions and a better answer rate would certainly help our chances :) 

I came to meta.quant looking for something along these lines. I was amused to see that this answer wasn't accepted by @emcor ;)
